# SQL: How can you release or prevent update/insert locks while remaining in the transaction?

Tags: mysql, locking

**Current situation:**

1. We're using mysql (percona) 8.0, with InnoDB tables
2. We're using read-committed transaction isolation, although we can switch to read-uncommitted because:
3. We don't use transactions or rollback anywhere (we always store our data with the last statement, if the last statement isn't executed, the data inserted is all removed/garbage-collected automatically over time)
4. We handle locking of our fields/data ourselves (outside of the database, it's completely separated from the database, think: redis locks), to prevent any race conditions

**The problem:**

We've noticed that if we run our code in a transaction, it speeds up dramatically (x5, for example, a large script/action goes down from 7500ms to 1500ms, timed in PHP). The downside is that it seems that updates (and inserts too?) create a lock, which normally (when not in a transaction) releases immediately, but in a transaction, it keeps the lock until the transaction is committed. This causes a lot of deadlocks, since the order of updates can't ever be guaranteed in our system, plus it conflicts with our own locking system.

We've tried to lower the transaction isolation level down to read-uncommitted, but it still creates locks that don't get released until the transaction is over.

**Question:**

Is there a way to disable locks generated by SQL (whether it's with MySQL+InnoDB or with any other database or table type), or is there a way to release those locks immediately while remaining in the transaction?

---

## Example:

**Our table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `data_global_field_2` (
  `index` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE `data_global_field_2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`index`);
```

**Part 1:**

Script 1:

```
$db->exec("DELETE FROM \"data_global_field_2\"");
sleep(6); // this sleep just makes it easier to make this race condition happen
$db->exec("INSERT INTO \"data_global_field_2\" (`index`, `value`) VALUES (1,'one'), (2,'two'), (3,'three'), (4,'four'), (5,'five')");
```

Script 2:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO \"data_global_field_2\" (`index`, `value`) VALUES (1,'something') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = 'something'");
```

Now, in this case, if script 1 and 2 are being run, script 2 will make a modification, and script 1 will error/fail. As far as I know, we can't make a SQL lock on non-existing rows.

**Part 2:**

We could use a semaphores table, but that would be the same as locking it with something external. So, because of this, we wrap it in our own lock, like so:

Script 1:

```
Synchronizer::syncEx('some key', static function () use (&$db)
{
    $db->exec("DELETE FROM \"data_global_field_2\"");
    sleep(6); // this sleep just makes it easier to make this race condition happen
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO \"data_global_field_2\" (`index`, `value`) VALUES (1,'one'), (2,'two'), (3,'three'), (4,'four'), (5,'five')");
});
```

Script 2:

```
Synchronizer::syncEx('some key', static function () use (&$db)
{
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO \"data_global_field_2\" (`index`, `value`) VALUES (1,'something') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = 'something'");
});
```

Then these two scripts would be executed one after another, which would work.

**Part 3:**

Now, this happens in our internal code, these actions, where a table (or part of it) is being cleared, and set to something else. Basically, multiple-query actions. For example, script 1 is executed as:

```
$GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']);
```

Now, if we run 2 scripts, like this:

Script 1:

```
$GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['aaa', 'bbb']);
sleep(3);
$GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['bbb', 'ccc']);
sleep(3);
$GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['ccc', 'ddd']);
```

Script 2:

```
$GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']);
```

Then this would work, since it would always grab one of our own locks before it runs any SQL, so any delete+insert action is isolated from the other deletes/inserts.

**Part 4:**

But, if we can put all of this in a transaction, then it would be many times faster, like this:

Script 1:

```
$db->transaction(static function () use (&$GLOBAL)
{
    $GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['aaa', 'bbb']);
    sleep(3);
    $GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['bbb', 'ccc']);
    sleep(3);
    $GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['ccc', 'ddd']);
});
```

Script 2:

```
$db->transaction(static function () use (&$GLOBAL)
{
    $GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']);
});
```

But, because it's in a transaction then, they will keep holding the SQL locks (most noticeably script 1 in this case). This will then cause script 2 to have our own lock, but then it also needs the SQL lock, but since script 1 still has the SQL lock, it can't get that. And since script 1 wants our own lock, which script 2 has, it too will be stuck. It will be deadlocked.

I hope this example makes sense.

Comment: I have seen this question once already today?

Comment: It was closed for some reason? Because apparently it was asking for "recommendations"? I'm not asking for recommendations though, just asking if SQL somehow allows this. Anyway to reopen the question, I've deleted the previous one and created a new one, with different questions to not imply I'm asking for recommendations, but rather a technical question about SQL itself.

Comment: I would guess, as thats all I can do, as we know nothing about your ___We handle locking of our fields/data ourselves___ that your locking techniques and the one's used by MySQL are whats getting in your way. Do you have a better description/example of your personall locking methods

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant, we just want to disable or unlock updates/inserts (SQL locks), it was just to provide a reason/context to the question. But anyway if you're interested, our locking system is similar to holding locks on redis. We lock on string keys, with read or write access (read allowing multiple reads at once, write only allowing 1 at once). To be more specific we don't use redis, since it was inefficient, we implemented our own java server and manage locks with that, but the result is the same.

Comment: So your locks dont actually lock the database at all, its a logical not physical lock like a semaphore

Comment: Yeah exactly. Our locks are completely separated from the database.

Comment: So my guess is way off like most guesses

Comment: No problem, glad to clear it up.

Comment: You have `autocommit=ON`?  And never user `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`?

Comment: Even 1500ms is a terribly long time for a single query.  Please provide an example of one that is that slow; maybe we can find a way to speed it up.

Comment: Yeah autocommit is by default on, and we never use begin/start transaction (except in a $db->action(function(){}) block, which starts a transaction, then later commits or rollbacks it based on whether the function ran successfully or whether it threw an exception. Anyway the 1500ms was for several queries, specifically it was for copying over ~200 objects, which have 4 fields, each stored in a different table. So the 1500ms was for about 800 insert queries.

Answer (score 1):

> We don't use transactions

Yes you do.

> We handle locking of our fields/data ourselves

No you don't.

> We've noticed that if we run our code in a transaction, it speeds up dramatically

Your code *always* runs in a transaction. By default, a SQL statement that isn't part of a `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` block will implicitly start such a block. That implicit block will automatically commit (thereby releasing its locks) at the end of the statement.

If you run more than one SQL statement "at one time", each of them will individually autocommit by default. If you run more than one SQL statement in one explicit transaction, all the SQL statements will commit "at the same time". That might have something to do with speed difference you see.

This is not a MySQL thing. It's a SQL thing. It's part of the SQL standard.

> Is there a way to disable locks generated by SQL (whether it's with
>   MySQL+InnoDB or with any other database or table type), or is there a
>   way to release those locks immediately while remaining in the
>   transaction?

You can't disable locks on any SQL dbms.

You can't release locks from *inside* a transaction without either commiting the transaction or rolling it back.

---

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: I see what you mean. We do however handle locking ourselves as well, so it's being done twice basically. Either way, if we can't disable/prevent locking or release them within a transaction, it means we can't put everything inside of one transaction, meaning we can't have the performance improvement from doing that? There's no way around it?

Comment: @patrick_vane: I'm not sure I understand your question. Edit your original question above, and paste a minimal version of your locking code, minimal `create table...` and `insert ...` statements that everyone here can use to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I've added an example to the original post, please let me know if that example is understandable/comprehensible.

Comment: @patrick_vane  It seems script 2 gets your own lock before script 1 committed its transaction. Why does it happen?

Comment: Because of the sleeps in this case, since script 1 grabs a lock, releases it, sleeps 3 seconds, grabs it, releases it, sleeps, etc. In a real-world scenario it could be anything, from http requests, to other database selects/updates/etc, etc. Notice that the lock isn't around the transaction (since that would mean each script can only execute at a rate of one at a time, which would be unusable. The lock is around the set/get/etc methods, like around (or rather in) $GLOBAL->fields['Strings']->set(...)

Comment: @patrick_vane As Mike said you can't remove locks from data updating queries till commit (MySQL Server needs to lock records to be able to update them). But I'm wondering do you receive speed improvement with large transaction even when you run only one script simultaneously? If your script contains a lot of data modification statements then you may try to change innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit value to decrease log flushing frequency (it may be the reason why large transaction works faster).

Comment: @Nikita Hmm that's interesting. Setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2 has reduced the time our example took from 7500 to 4200 milliseconds. Still, if we then wrap that with a transaction, it is further reduced from 4200 to 1100 milliseconds.

Comment: @patrick_vane Is it possible that in your script you update the same rows several times? Or when you run separate transactions (your default solution) you recreate a connection each time? Do you run your test on dev server without any other workload?

Comment: Yeah we update the same row in our test. We don't recreate connections, for sure. We aren't really in production yet, but we've tested it out on several systems and they all produce the same result.

Comment: @patrick_vane Maybe it would be possible to modify your script to update rows only once. Also your description looks like you probably use "cursor based" approach and maybe it has a sense to rewrite your scripts using "set based" one. And the fact you are facing with locking/deadlocking problem can mean that you may get different results when using explicit transactions (it's hard to say for sure without knowing the whole picture).

Comment: I'm not sure what set-based or cursor-based means? We can't determine what rows etc get updated since our users program the code, we have made a system with which they do so, which makes it a lot easier to do what they want/need to do. Because of this, we can only decide/control what happens inside the get(), set(), append(), etc functions, but we can't decide/control if a field gets updated, if it happens once or twice or more, in what order it happens, etc.

Comment: @patrick_vane I mean maybe it's possible to combine your scripts or queries inside the script to run one big update for multiple rows instead of execution of dozens of separate queries.

Comment: Hey we're thinking the same. We'll add batch functions, to set multiple fields/objects at once, which will all be done in a single transaction then. Thanks for the help/support!

Comment: @patrick_vane: INNOdb supports shared locks, exclusive locks, intention shared locks, intention exclusive locks, record locks, gap locks, next-key locks, insert intention locks, AUTO-INC locks, and predicate locks. Which ones are you using to handle locking yourselves?

Comment: We don't use any SQL locks, intentionally at least. Our own system locks on the field that is being get/set, with gets running in shared locks and sets running in exclusive locks. Anyway we were able to make all sets happen in a batch, all running in one transaction, which has reduced the execution time to about 900 ms. It runs faster than the all-in-transaction solution we had first, since now we can also merge queries together, and skip some of our own locking as well.

Comment: There still is one downside, and that's that the user can't ever use transactions (for the rollback functionality), since it would all deadlock if the user would open a transaction and executes several changes (updates/inserts/deletes) in there. Luckily with these batch sets, we can rollback any changes that happened if something in it fails/errors, but that would still be limited to changing one field. Anyway I wonder how others solve the use-case/example we've wrote down in the question.

Comment: I guess in step 2 you could lock it somehow, with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE? We've tried doing that but it didn't work, but it might be because we use isolation level read-committed.

Answer (score 0):

For "Part 1", avoid `DELETE` as a way to clear a table...

Plan A:  Instead, do `TRUNCATE TABLE t`.

Plan B:  Use this sequence:

1. `CREATE TABLE t_new LIKE t`;
2. Insert the values into `t_new`.
3. `RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_new TO t;
4. `DROP TABLE t_old`

Plan A avoids locking every row of the table.  Plan B avoids any downtime for access to the table by atomically swapping in the new data.

(As for turning off transactional semantics -- not possible in InnoDB.  MyISAM has no such functionality; instead, it locks entire tables, which mya lead to worse problems.)

Comment: Often times it's not the whole table that has to be removed. In this example it could be, but we also have 'objects' and 'users', that in the database have an 'id', 'index' and 'value' then. In that case, we want to only remove the 'indexes'/'values' of a given 'id' then. Because of this, we can't delete/clear/truncate the whole table.

Comment: For deleting a few ids, there should be no problem.  For deleting a large part of the table see other techniques in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig